# Guice named inject in eager singleton

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice, inject

There is Java class which should have `int MY_LISTENER_PORT` with injected my.listener.port value from a properties file:

```
@Singleton
public class MyListener {

    @Inject
    @Named("my.listener.port")
    private int MY_LISTENER_PORT;

    public MyListener(){
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Port: " + MY_LISTENER_PORT);
    }
}
```

Which is bind as eager singleton with Guice in:

```
public class BootstrapServletModule extends ServletModule {

     @Override
     protected void configureServlets() {
          ...
          bind(MyListener.class).asEagerSingleton();
          ...
     }
}
```

Sometimes when Tomcat starts up, I get properly injected value to MY_LISTENER_PORT, for example: "Port: 9999". Sometimes, it is not injected and I get "Port: 0". Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is could be simply you constructor fires before 'MY_LISTER_PORT' gets chance to get injected

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectionPoints

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Bootstrap

constructors are injected before methods and fields, as you have to construct an instance before injecting its members.

> Injections are performed in a specific order. All fields are injected
>   and then all methods. Within the fields, supertype fields are injected
>   before subtype fields. Similarly, supertype methods are injected
>   before subtype methods.

User constructor injection

```
@Inject
public MyListener(@Named("my.listener.port") int port){
        this.MY_LISTER_PORT = port;
        start();
    }
```